# How to rewrite this without using exec()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How can this code be rewritten without the use of exec() if possible? I have tried finding a way myself but I am relatively new to coding and can't seem to figure it out.

```
def make_button(self, date, row, column):
    """
    Description:
        Build a date button.

    :param date: date.
    :type date: string

    :param row: row number.
    :type row: string

    :param column: column number.
    :type column: string
    """
    exec(
        "self.btn_" + date + " = ttk.Button(self.frame_days, text=" + date
        + ", width=5)\n"
        "self.btn_" + date + ".grid(row=" + row + " , column=" + column
        + ")\n"
        "self.btn_" + date + ".bind(\"<Button-1>\", self.get_date)"
    )
```

and

```
    def delete_buttons(self, date):
    """
    Description:
        Delete a date button.

    :param date: date.
    :type: string
    """
    exec(
        "self.btn_" + str(date) + ".destroy()"
    )
```

Comment: where this `btn_*` came from?

Comment: Dup: [How do you programmatically set an attribute?](//stackoverflow.com/q/285061) and [getting dynamic attribute in python](//stackoverflow.com/q/13595690) or [How do I create a variable number of variables?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1373164)

Comment: also you probably should ask your question at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: short answer: dictionaries. `self.btn[date] = ttk.Button(...)`